# Error while running PySAL SpaceTimeEvents function

Tags: pysal

I'm new to PySAL and trying to run Knox test to find space-time correlation in my dataset. My original dataset is in the form of csv including attributes such latitude, longitude, date and other related features. I converted the csv file into shapefile (point-type shapefile) using QGIS. I stored the .shp, .dbf and .shx in a folder in pysal/examples directory.

I'm trying to run these lines of code:

```
import numpy as np
import pysal
import pysal.spatial_dynamics.interaction as interaction
np.random.seed(100)
path = "...pysal/examples/Shapefile/trial.shp"
events = interaction.SpaceTimeEvents(path, 'Date', infer_timestamp = True)
```

(source: http://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/tutorials/dynamics.html#space-time-interaction-tests)

I'm facing the following error even though the trial.dbf file is present in the same folder:

> KeyError: 'trial.dbf not found in PySAL built-in examples.'

Can anyone guide me as to what I'm doing wrong here?

What is the solution for this error?

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**: You can fix this by changing one line of code but I also will do a pull request for the `pysal` library to make sure no one else has the issue in the future.

**Details**:
The problem is [line 124 in line](https://github.com/pysal/pysal/blob/master/pysal/spatial_dynamics/interaction.py#L124) in the `pysal` source code for the `SpaceTimeEvents` class.  As stated, I will submit a pull request to the Pysal project, but in the meantime you can use these instructions to get the module working locally for yourself.

**Solution**: You must change a line of code for your locally installed version of `pysal`.  To find out where your local `pysal` install is, follow these directions. Open a python interpreter, and then:

```
# loading libraries
import pysal,os

# this line finds where your pysal is installed and prints it out
head,tail=os.path.split(pysal.__file__)

# this will print out the location of the file you need to change
print(os.path.join(head,"spatial_dynamics/interaction.py"))
```

If you run the code above, it should print the location of the pysal file you need to change.  Now, navigate to that file.

Open that file in a text editor or a word pad. You will change line 124 from:

```
# this is the old pysal code causing the error
dbf = pysal.open(pysal.examples.get_path(dbf_tail))
```

to

```
# replace the code above with this code
dbf = pysal.open(os.path.join(head,dbf_tail))
```

Save the edited file.  Re-import pysal (you may have to restart your python), and try using SpaceTimeEvents to load your local file. It should work!